# Infinite isometry in subset of Euclidean plane

Tags: group-theory, geometry, isometry

Is there an example of a nonempty bounded subset of the Euclidean plane which has an infinite isometry group?

Would the unit cube $[0,1]^n$ be an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a circle.

$[0,1]^n$ is not a subset of the Euclidean plane, and its isometry group (for any norm) is finite.
It is nonempty and bounded, though.

Comment: ah I meant unit square, sorry...but that wouldn't be applicable here anyway since it's isometry group would be finite as well, correct? So the unit circle has an infinite isometry group?

Comment: @mathl0v3r Yes. The square has only a few isometries, while any rotation of the circle, no matter how small, is an isometry.

Comment: thank you! so would a unit hyperbola be another example then?

Comment: No, a hyperbola has only four isometries (the identity, two reflections and a rotation).